# How can I solve this problem: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm using Flutter, I want to to find all the products in a given snapshot and then return a list of products from a snapshot.
But it there is an error says "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'."

**Source Code**

```
// product list from snapshot
  List<Product> _productListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Product(
        id: doc.id,
        name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
        price: doc.data()['price'].toDouble() ?? '',
        description: doc.data()['description'] ?? '',
        imageUrls: doc.data()['imageUrls'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

**Screenshot**

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dnbz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only cast the values with **dynamic**:

```
// product list from snapshot
  List<Product> _productListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Product(
        id: doc.id,
        name: (doc.data() as dynamic)['name'] ?? '',
        price: (doc.data() as dynamic)['price'].toDouble() ?? '',
        description: (doc.data() as dynamic)['description'] ?? '',
        imageUrls: (doc.data() as dynamic)['imageUrls'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```